# Java ArrayList different objects extend each other, how to get to know object I've retrieved?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, polymorphism

So Java is not my strong point and so I'm now stuck.  Here is a simple explanation

```
public class UserGroup {
  protected List<User> users = new ArrayList();
  protected String name;
}

public class User {
  private String username;
}

public class Tutor extends User {
  private String subject;
}

public class Student extends User {
  private String grade;
}
```

My problem is if I add things to the list that might be a user, tutor or student, when I get the object back later (by walking arraylist) how do I know which object type it is so I know if I have access to .grade, .subject etc?

Or am I missing something completely, I feel like I should be using generics here somehow.

Comment: Minor point: You will get better help, and your life will be simpler and happier, if you follow java's naming conventions of class names starting with a capital letters. Because you are a beginner, I have corrected that plus the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Please, follow the Java code style conventions and provide compilable code.

Comment: You are using a raw type for your ArrayList. It should be `List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
User user = users.get(i);
if (user instanceof Tutor) {
  Tutor tutor = (Tutor) user;
  // tutor.subject
} else if (user instance of Student) {
  Student student = (Student) user;
  // student.grade
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The more important question *why* do you want to know the exact type?

Following the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if you have a collection of user object, you should be able to perform all operations on them without knowing their type.

If you need to know the type, you probably should not be dealing with a collection of users at that point. Either create two lists - one for each type - or design you classes so you don't need to know their exact type.

Comment: @Paul yes, for example I would think you would have a `Subject` that has a `List<Tutor> tutors`. And possibly Tutor would have `List<Subject> subjects` that they *can* teach (not necessarily *are* teaching - you would check the tutors of a subject to know who is actually teaching which subjects).

Answer (score 0):

Use a map structure where a key specifies the type and value is the list of particular user classes using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
Map<Class<?>, List<User>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getClass));
```

The resulting map would look like below:

```
class com.comany.User [User{name="a"}, User{name="e"}, User{name="f"}]
class com.comany.Tutor [Tutor{name="c"}]
class com.comany.Student [Student{name="b"}, Student{name="d"}]
```

A particular list can be accessed through `Map::get`:

```
List<Tutor> tutors = map.get(Tutor.class);
```